# 2d array always index to 0

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

i have this code in countrySegment.php:

```
  <tbody>
            <?php

            require 'class.php';
            require './session.php';
            $conn = new db_class();
            $read = $conn->select();
            $test = $conn->readSegments();

            while ($fetch = $read->fetch_array()) {

                ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="country[]" value=" <?php echo $fetch['id'] ?>"/>
                        <?php echo $fetch['country'] ?>

                    </td>
                    <td><select name="segment[<?php echo $fetch['id']; ?>][]" id="">
                            <option></option>
                            <?php
                            $reads = $conn->readSegments();

                            $country_id = $fetch['id'];
                            $country_segment_id = $conn->getCountrySegment($country_id)->fetch_array();


                            while ($fetch = $reads->fetch_array()) {

                                ?>

                                <option <?php if($country_segment_id['segment_id'] == $fetch['id']){ echo "selected=\"selected\" ";}?> value="<?php echo $fetch['id'];?>"><?php echo $fetch['segment'];?></option>

                            <?php } ?>

                        </select>
                    </td>
                        <td><select name="segment[<?php echo $country_id; ?>][]" id="">

                            <?php
                            $reada = $conn->readSegments();




                            while ($fetch = $reada->fetch_array()) {
                                ?>

                                <option value="<?php echo $fetch['id'];?>" ><?php echo $fetch['segment'];?></option>

                            <?php } ?>

                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            <?php }


            ?>


            </tbody>
```

and this is the action where the post goes:

```
<?php print_r($_POST['segment']);require_once "class.php";if (isset($_POST['country'])) {

$countrys = $_POST['country'];
$segments = $_POST['segment'];  foreach ($countrys as $keyC => $country) {
    foreach ($segments as $keyS => $segment) {

        if ($keyC == $keyS) {
            // logic go here

            $db = new db_class();
           $db->selectCountrySegment($country, $segment);
           echo '


    ';
        }

    }
}

$allKeys = array_keys($segments);
// echo $allKeys[0];


for ($i = 0; $i < count($segments); $i++) {
    echo "Country id =".$allKeys[$i]." has:";
    $country=$allKeys[$i];
    for ($l = 0; $l < count($segments[$i]); $l++) {
        echo "segment".$segments[$i][$l];
        $segment= $segments[$i][$l];
        $db = new db_class();
        $db->selectCountrySegment($country, $segment);
    }

}
```

and i have this output:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 20 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 20 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 20 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 20 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 20 ) [7] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 20 ) [8] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 20 ) [9] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 20 ) [10] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 20 ) )
```

so the problem is always the index of the array is 0, and it always take same segments for all

and then i have these 2 notices:`Notice: Undefined offset: 0` in this line:`for ($l = 0; $l < count($segments[$i]); $l++) {`

please help its my first time i use 2d arrays thank u

Comment: Your (outer) array does not have an element with index `0`. What is the exact line that causes the error?

Comment: this:    for ($l = 0; $l < count($segments[$i]); $l++) {  @TomUdding

Comment: Check the answer by @Orifjon.

Comment: still have the same problem @TomUdding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$segments` array starts with index `0`, change your code to this:

```
$segments = array(
    1 => array(1, 2),
    2 => array(3, 4),
    3 => array(5, 6),
    4 => array(7, 8),
    5 => array(9, 10)
);

$allKeys = array_keys($segments);

for ($i = 1; $i <= count($segments); $i++) {
//       ^^^
    echo "Country id =".$allKeys[$i-1]." has:";
//                               ^^^^
    $country=$allKeys[$i-1];
//                    ^^^^
    for ($l = 0; $l < count($segments[$i]); $l++) {
        echo "segment".$segments[$i][$l]."<br>";
        $segment= $segments[$i][$l];
        $db = new db_class();
        $db->selectCountrySegment($country, $segment);
    }

}
```

If you start with `0` `count($segments[$i])` (in `for ($l = 0; $l < count($segments[$i]); $l++) {`) will throw the error because `$segments[0]` does not exist.

I recommend to put the `count($segments)` outside the for-loop, it improves the execution time of your script. See [PHP benchmark for-loop test](http://www.phpbench.com).

Answer (score 0):

your $segments array starts from 1, so there is no element at $segments[0]

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 20 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 20 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 20 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 20 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 20 ) [7] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 20 ) [8] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 20 ) [9] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 20 ) [10] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 20 ) )
```

you can change it to start from 1

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($segments); $i++) {
echo "Country id =".$allKeys[$i]." has:";
$country=$allKeys[$i];
    for ($l = 0; $l < count($segments[$i+1]); $l++) {
        echo "segment".$segments[$i+1][$l];
        $segment= $segments[$i+1][$l];
        $db = new db_class();
        $db->selectCountrySegment($country, $segment);
    }
}
```